# como generar el orm de esta consulta, me da error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

Buenas tardes como genero esta consulta:

```
select n_id,n_id_primero
from dt_material
where n_id = n_id_primero
```

Intente de esta forma:

```
$material = Material::select('n_id','n_id_primero')
                            ->whereNull('d_fecha_eliminacion')
                             ->where('n_id_primero','n_id')
                             ->orderBy('v_nombre_material', 'asc')
                             ->get();
```

Muestra este error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "n_id" (SQL: select "n_id", "v_nombre_material", "n_id_primero", (select v_descripcion
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar y esta es la respuesta:

```
$material = Material::select('n_id','n_id_primero')
                            ->whereNull('d_fecha_eliminacion')
                            ->whereNull('d_fecha_eliminacion')
                            ->whereColumn('n_id', '=', 'n_id_primero')
                            ->orderBy('v_nombre_material','asc')
                            ->get();
```